# VOID Pointer for C DLL written in CTYPES

Tags: c#, python-2.7, wrapper, ctypes

I am attempting to convert a C# program to python. The DLL is wrapped in C, and I have been able to use CTYPES on all functions but I am having issues with 2 remaining functions, they are very similar.

The function

```
LONG SetMe(LONG Dev, BYTE Length, STRUCTURE_SETTINGS StructureSettings, void* data, DWORD dataSize);
```

Parameters
Dev - input
Length - input
StructureSettings - input
data - Ouput
dataSize - input

I am able to run the function and the DLL does respond but it does not return any values. How do should I deal with VOID pointer return? I really want to stay in the CTYPES realm.

Here is the code dump with the structure information

```
class STRUCTURE_SETTINGS(Structure):
_fields_ = [
('T', c_byte),
('C', c_byte),
('I', c_byte),
('reserve', c_byte),
('Dev1', c_byte),
('Dev2', c_byte),
('Dev3', c_byte),
('Dev4', c_byte)]   

Main Code....

Dev = 0
Length = 1
dataSize=4
data = ctypes.c_uint * dataSize
dataPointer = data()

StructureSettings = STRUCTURE_SETTINGS() 
StructureSettings.T = 0x01
StructureSettings.C = 0x0
StructureSettings.I = 0x4
StructureSettings.Dev1 = 0x0
StructureSettings.Dev2 = 0x0
StructureSettings.Dev3 = 0x0
StructureSettings.Dev4 = 0x0


getFuncDLL = localDll.Setme
getFuncDLL.argtypes = [c_long, c_int, ctypes.POINTER(STRUCTURE_SETTINGS), c_void_p, c_ulonglong]
getFuncDLL.restype = c_long
getFuncDLLreturn = getFuncDLL(Dev, Length, StructureSettings, data, dataSize)   

getFuncDLLreturn....for error return codes
data is the value the I am looking for.
```

Comment: The return I currently get is nothing.  The dataSize is the amount of data I want to return and the value should be in a integer or a hex value.  I will try your suggestion.

Comment: The return I currently get is nothing.  The dataSize is the amount of data I want to return and the value should be in a integer or a hex value.  I tried your suggestion and it returned nothing back.  I set the argtype of the DLL to c_void_p, and did a byref(data) then repr(data.raw) and returned '\x00\x00\x00\x00' the result from the code I am running should return the IP address of the device I am talking too.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: See above added more code information

Comment: I fixed my problem.... I had to remove the argtype setting and just pass in the variables directly.

Comment: @user3277599, you should post the fix as an answer, so this question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to the problem was deleting the following lines:

getFuncDLL.argtypes = [c_long, c_int, ctypes.POINTER(STRUCTURE_SETTINGS), c_void_p, c_ulonglong]
getFuncDLL.restype = c_long